# How do I find the variable names and values that are saved in a checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to see the variables that are saved in a TensorFlow checkpoint along with their values. How can I find the variable names that are saved in a TensorFlow checkpoint?

I used `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` which is explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/861644c0bcae5d56f7b3f439696eefa6df8580ec/tensorflow/python/training/saver_test.py#L1203). But, it is not given in the documentation of TensorFlow. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`inspect_checkpoint.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) tool.

So, for example, if you stored the checkpoint in the current directory, then you can print the variables and their values as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file


latest_ckp = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(latest_ckp, all_tensors=True, tensor_name='')
```

Comment: it prints variable names and values, but doesn't return them... how to return just variable names stored in a checkpoint?

Comment: @kurtosis you can change the code to return both names and weights.

Answer (score 54):

**Example usage:**

```py
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
import os
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.ckpt")

# List ALL tensors example output: v0/Adam (DT_FLOAT) [3,3,1,80]
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=checkpoint_path, tensor_name='')

# List contents of v0 tensor.
# Example output: tensor_name:  v0 [[[[  9.27958265e-02   7.40226209e-02   4.52989563e-02   3.15700471e-02
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=checkpoint_path, tensor_name='v0')

# List contents of v1 tensor.
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=checkpoint_path, tensor_name='v1')
```

***Update:*** `all_tensors` argument was added to `print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file` since [Tensorflow 0.12.0-rc0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e0344f1e7ceff9c192369000d244c4ca47d7a1cc#diff-fb7984719b22f01a7748ef847e9eb731) so you may need to add `all_tensors=False` or `all_tensors=True` if required.

**Alternative method:**

```py
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
import os

checkpoint_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.ckpt")
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(checkpoint_path)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()

for key in var_to_shape_map:
    print("tensor_name: ", key)
    print(reader.get_tensor(key)) # Remove this is you want to print only variable names
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

A few more details.

If your model is saved using V2 format, for example, if we have the following files in the directory `/my/dir/`

```
model-10000.data-00000-of-00001
model-10000.index
model-10000.meta
```

then the `file_name` parameter should only be the prefix, that is

```
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='/my/dir/model_10000', tensor_name='', all_tensors=True)
```

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7696 for a discussion.

Answer (score 7):

An update to the answers mentioned above

For latest Tensorflow versions (verified on TF 1.13+), a cleaner way to do is as follows

```
ckpt_reader = tf.train.load_checkpoint(ckpt_dir_or_file)
value = ckpt_reader.get_tensor(name_of_the_tensor)
```

The `name_of_the_tensor` should correspond the variable name (whose value you're trying to inspect). To get a list of variable names and shapes in a checkpoint, you can check via

```
vars_list = tf.train.list_variables(ckpt_dir_or_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding more parameter details to `print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file`

`file_name`: not a physical file, just the prefix of filenames

If no `tensor_name` is provided, prints the tensor names and shapes
in the checkpoint file. If `tensor_name` is provided, prints the content of the tensor.([inspect_checkpoint.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23c218785eac5bfe737eec4f8081fd0ef8e0684d/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py#L36-L39))

If `all_tensor_names` is `True`, Prints all the tensor names

If `all_tensor` is 'True`, Prints all the tensor names and the corresponding content.

**N.B.** `all_tensor` and `all_tensor_names` will override `tensor_name`

Answer (score 0):

To add a side note,  print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file can not print all values in a big tensor (some values will be omitted as '...'). To see all the values, you can use code like the following

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader('/dir/to/ckpt/model.ckpt-81230')
t = reader.get_tensor('YOUR_TENSOR_NAME_HERE')
# t is an numpy array, and you can check it like print(list(t))
```