# How does one inspect variables in a checkpoint file in TensorFlow when TensorFlow can't find the tools attribute?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to inspect checkpoints using the code at [inspect_checkpoint.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py). However, I wasn't able to have it work because they didn't really provide an example. I tried the simplest thing I thought would work:

```
tf.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='./tmp/mdl_ckpt',tensor_name='',all_tensors='')
```

however I get that `python` has no attribute `tools`:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python' has no attribute 'tools'
```

it seems like a (embarrassingly) trivial bug/issue. Does someone know what is going on? Why can't it find tools? Also, even if it did find it, how would one run the function provided in that file?

---

Unfortunately, the very related question did not really provide an answer of how to get around this issue. The question is here [How can find the variable names that saved in tensorflow checkpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218174/how-can-find-the-variable-names-that-saved-in-tensorflow-checkpoint)

Comment: Works for me. What version of tensorflow are you using? Did you install via pip or from source?

Comment: @DomJack Im using `tensorflow (0.12.1)` and I simply used pip install. Also python version 3.5.1. What about you? Also what did you run, exactly what I wrote?

Comment: python: 2.7.6, tensorflow: 0.12.1 Code:

from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file;

print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='./tmp/mdl_ckpt',tensor_name='',all_tensors='')

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='./tmp/mdl_ckpt', tensor_name='', all_tensors=False)
```

The `all_tensors` argument was added since [Tensorflow 0.12.0-rc0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e0344f1e7ceff9c192369000d244c4ca47d7a1cc#diff-fb7984719b22f01a7748ef847e9eb731).

Comment: Is there any way to print layers in order?

Answer (score 4):

Well, isn't inspect_checkpoint.py a binary?

Something like this might work:

```
bazel run tensorflow/python/tools:inspect_checkpoint -- --file_name=YOUR_CKPT
```

EDIT:

Or without bazel:

Find where tensorflow is installed and run the command with `python`:

```
python PATH_TO_VENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py --file_name=YOUR_CKPT
```

For all options, see the file itself: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py

Comment: ah binary? Sorry if Im terribly confused about this, but the link I provided as far as I can tell links to a python file or am I wrong?

Comment: also what is bazel? Why do I need bazel?

Comment: It's likely the pip installation doesn't install -all- of the tools. Bazel is google's open source build tool - so if you install from source, bazel is what you use. Not sure how to do what you want from the pip installation, but I can confirm the built-from-source version has the appropriate tools built.

Comment: @DomJack are you saying I need to re-install tensorflow? From source? last time I tried it was a super pain.

Comment: Bazel is what you use to compile tensorflow from source. It doesn't need to be. The point is that inspect_checkpoint is actually a binary rather than a library, so you can run it from the commandline directly. I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of latest stable TensorFlow version, 1.13, and in the upcoming TF 2.0, to most straightforward way to inspect a checkpoint is:

```py
path = './tmp/mdl_ckpt' 
get_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path) 
#this retrieves the latest checkpoin file form path, but it also can be set manually

inspect_list = tf.train.list_variables(get_checkpoint)
```

This creates a list of all variable names in given checkpoint

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [command line interface](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#cli_to_inspect_and_execute_savedmodel) that uses `inspect_checkpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint --file_name bad_model/epoch-233

python -m tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint --file_name bad_model/epoch-233 --all_tensors

python -m tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint --file_name bad_model/epoch-233 --all_tensor_names
```