# Issue with saving/restoring batch norm layers (TensorFlow)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying a model with a number of batch norm layers in there. The issue is when I restore the model, it seems to be picking random weights (and not population weights out of training) for the batch norm layers and produces bad testing outputs.

I have looked at multiple solutions posted online but haven't had luck yet. Please take a look at the code below (encompasses solutions I've tried)

I have looked around stackoverflow and tried various solutions including adding batch norm dependencies and making sure saver var_list is specified. Nothing seems to work.

I am using Tensorflow version 1.10 and I have also tried using save_npz and load_and_assign_npz (same issue there).

Here is how a part of my model looks like to give you an idea -

1.model.py

```
def _batch_normalization(input_tensor, is_train, gamma_init, name):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(input_tensor, training=is_train, name=name)

gamma_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(1., 0.02)

with tf.variable_scope("u_net_bn", reuse=reuse):
    tl.layers.set_name_reuse(reuse)
    inputs = InputLayer(x, name='inputs')

    conv1 = Conv2d(inputs, 64, (3, 3), act=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_1')

    conv1 = _batch_normalization(conv1.outputs, is_train=is_train, gamma_init=gamma_init, name='bn1')

    conv1 = InputLayer(conv1, name='bn1_fix')

    conv1 = Conv2d(conv1, 64, (3, 3), act=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_2')

    conv1 = _batch_normalization(conv1.outputs, is_train=is_train, gamma_init=gamma_init, name='bn2')

    conv1 = InputLayer(conv1, name='bn2_fix')

    pool1 = MaxPool2d(conv1, (2, 2), name='pool1')

    conv2 = Conv2d(pool1, 128, (3, 3), act=tf.nn.relu, name='conv2_1')
```

2.main.py

```
 with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):

     ## Pretrain

     g_optim_init = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr_v, beta1=beta1).minimize(mse_loss, var_list=g_vars)

     ## SRGAN

     g_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr_v, beta1=beta1).minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)

     d_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr_v, beta1=beta1).minimize(d_loss, var_list=d_vars)
```

Save --

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.global_variables())
savepath = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_dir + '/g_{}_{}_init.npz'.format(tl.global_flag['mode'], epoch))

Restore --

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False))

saver = tf.train.Saver()

saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./checkpoint'))
```

Comment: Could you make sure that the checkpoint contains BN variables? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41870281/262432

Answer (score 0):

It hard to say what is wrong in your particular case without looking at the full source code. Saving/restoring the BN layer seems to work OK.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.10.0'
>>> bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 1)))
>>> init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> sess.run(init)
>>> sess.run(tf.global_variables())
[array([1.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32)]
```

Note that all global variables have been created by the BN layer. The training loop will be doing incremental updates which could be emulated by the following.

```
>>> for v in tf.global_variables():
...     sess.run(v.assign([42]))
... 
array([42.], dtype=float32)
array([42.], dtype=float32)
array([42.], dtype=float32)
array([42.], dtype=float32)
```

All variables are now equal to `[42]`. Time to save/restore.

```
>>> saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
>>> saver.save(sess, "/tmp/chkpt")
'/tmp/chkpt'
>>> sess.run(init)  # Reinitialize all variables.
>>> sess.run(tf.global_variables())
[array([1.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32)]
```

The last two lines ensure that the variables are reset to their initial values. Finally

```
>>> saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/chkpt")
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/chkpt
>>> sess.run(tf.global_variables())
[array([42.], dtype=float32), array([42.], dtype=float32), array([42.], dtype=float32), array([42.], dtype=float32)]
```